# Google Cloud App has more that 100 users in test mode - how to remove them?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-developers-console

my Google Cloud Platform App is in Test mode in order to be later submitted to Google for approvation.
This App was proviously in production, so there are more that 100 accounts authenticated to the APP.

This means that I'm above the limit for 100 max users in Test mode and I cannot add new account i need to make some test.
I'm not able to find a way to list the currently authenticated users and remove them.
Anyone could help?

[limit of 100 users reacher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byrhc.png)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to list the users who have authorized your application, there is also no way for you to remove them. You need to wait for verification of your application before you can add new users.

## option one

If you have refresh tokens for the users you can try to revoke them and see if that grants you another additional users.  However my research says this will not help as the 100 limit appears to be the number of users who have granted your application authorization not the number of users who currently are authorized by your application.

## option two

You could also create new project and go though the verification process again, this time taking care not to gather have to many users before the verification process has been completed.